# How can I connect to an Azure Database SQL using JDBC in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, jdbc

In my Databricks cluster under Advance option in JDBC/ODBC I can see the following

```
Server host name: XX
Port: 443
Protocol: HTTPS
HTTP path: sql/protocolv1/o/11673698219XXXXX/0714-XXXXX-XXXXXXXX
JDBC URL: 2.6.25 or later
and a URL
```

I want to connect to an Azure SQL server I have and get data from it.
My current code is:

```
def get_azure_sql():
     mssql_server = os.getenv("MSSQL_SERVER")
     mssql_database = os.getenv("MSSQL_DATABASE")
     mssql_username = os.getenv("MSSQL_USERNAME")
     mssql_password = os.getenv("MSSQL_PASSWORD")
     mssql_port = os.getenv("MSSQL_PORT")
     mssql_driver = os.getenv("MSSQL_DRIVER")
    
    connection_url = f"""jdbc:sqlserver://{mssql_server}:{mssql_port};
database={mssql_database};user={mssql_username}@XXXX;
password{mssql_password};encrypt=true;
trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"""
    
    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_url)
    conn_str = f"""jdbc:sqlserver:///?autocommit=true&serverNameAsDNS=true&odbc_connect={params}"""
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str)
    return engine

engine = get_azure_sql()

with engine.connect() as conn:
    data = conn.execute("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [dbo].[Copy_of_Results]")
```

I am getting the following error

```
Could not parse SQLAlchemy URL from string 'jdbc:sqlserver:///?autocommit=true&serverNameAsDNS=true&odbc_connect=jdbc%3Asqlserver%3A%2F%2F{server_name}%3A1433%3Bdatabase%3D{database}%3Buser%3D{username}%40{XXXX}%3Bpassword%3D87BeVo%40Zh8EZgNk9qNhEJe-%40%3B%0A++++++++++++++++++++encrypt%3Dtrue%3BtrustServerCertificate%3Dfalse%3BhostNameInCertificate%3D%2A.database.windows.net%3BloginTimeout%3D30%3B'
```

Comment: Well you're trying to embed a `jdbc:sqlserver://` URL within another `jdbc:sqlserver://` URL, so don't do that. Probably you should be constructing the URL from its constituent parameters by way of `URL.create()` which you can then supply directly to `create_engine()` as demonstrated at [Creating URLs Programmatically](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#creating-urls-programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

When I am connecting to the SQL server with jdbc driver I got the similar error.

[image]

In your case URL is not build in correct format. I have created the URL in below format.

```
mssql_Url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{mssql_server}:{mssql_port};databaseName={mssql_database}"
```

with the help of below jdbc driver I connected to the SQL database directly.

```
mssql_driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

Complete code:

```
def get_azure_sql(table):
  mssql_server = "<serverName>.database.windows.net"
  mssql_database = "<dbName>"
  mssql_username = "<userName>"
  mssql_password = "<password>"
  mssql_port = "1433"
  mssql_driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"     
  mssql_Url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{mssql_server}:{mssql_port};databaseName={mssql_database}"
  table = "student"
  df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", mssql_driver).option("url", mssql_Url).option("dbtable", table).option("user", mssql_username).option("password", mssql_password).load()
  df1.show()
get_azure_sql("<tableName>")
```

I am able to connect SQL database successfully without any error:

[image]